# Are there any alternatves to using Pyro Event Server (subscribe) - by using Pyro4 or other packages?

Tags: python, pyro, pyro4

I'm updating a code (originally written in python 2.7) to be compatible with both python 2.7 and python 3. The code used the package Pyro(3) which doesn't seem to be compatible with python 3, so I've tried to use Pyro4 instead. Although using Pyro4 has helped solve some of the problems I was having it doesn't seem have the Event Server (subscribe) feature that was in Pyro (unless I'm missing something obvious??).

Has it been renamed to something else in Pyro4, or is there another way that I can use subscriber in Pyro4? If not is there another package that anyone can recommend that can be used instead?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, Pyro4 doesn't provide an event service as standard part of the library.

Now, the event service in Pyro3 was very basic. It should be easy to rebuilt it yourself on Pyro4, it should be a few dozen lines of code at most. But I suggest to also have a look at the '[messagebus](https://github.com/irmen/Pyro4/tree/master/examples/messagebus)' example that comes with Pyro4 already.

That's all I can say really, because you didn't tell us any specific details about what the requiremens on your communication layer in your application are (other than that it used to use Pyro3)